# Emacs debug-on-error not triggering for longlines-mode error

Tags: debugging, emacs

I'm running into a repeated error where switching to certain files results in seeing the following error 50% of the time.[0]

```
Symbol's function definition is void: longlines-mode
```

The file switch fails when I see this error.

In the `*Messages*` buffer, I see:

```
run-hooks: Symbol's function definition is void: longlines-mode
```

As far as I can tell, nothing in my `init.el` or referenced files uses `longlines-mode`.

After running `(setq debug-on-error t)`, I continue to see the message, but do not get dropped into a backtrace.

Running `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0, NS apple-appkit-1265.21) of 2014-10-20 on builder10-9.porkrind.org`

My questions are

1) How do I track down this error?

2) Why does `debug-on-error` not work?

[0] When I say 50%, I literally mean 50%. If I repeatedly run `timeclock-visit-timelog` (just one file where it happens), I will get the error. The next run I won't. The run after I will...

The behavior does not happen for all file types. `.java` files are not affected. `.org` files are. Opening IRC is.

Comment: Is the problem reproducible with `emacs -q` (prevents loading any user config)?  If not, grep your entire config, including elpa, to try to find it.  If that comes up empty, start bisecting your init.el to find what causes it.  Once you find it, consider switching to `visual-line-mode` (which should exist in 24.4) or filing a bug report for the offending package.  `longlines` is obsolete.  I'm not sure why `debug-on-error` isn't working, my guess is that `run-hook` is wrapped in a `condition-case`.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still not sure why the debug didn't work, but I found that I'd added visual-lines-mode one place in my config but failed to remove it elsewhere. Lesson: grep more carefully before posting...